# trying to install easyocr

Tags: python, easyocr

command run in py 3.11

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\python\My Heroes> pip install easyocr
```

output released

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\python\My Heroes> pip install easyocr
Collecting easyocr
  Using cached easyocr-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (2.1.0.dev20230310+cpu)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.5 in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from easyocr) (0.15.0.dev20230310+cpu)
Collecting opencv-python-headless<=4.5.4.60
  Using cached opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.60.tar.gz (89.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting scikit-build
        Using cached scikit_build-0.16.7-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
      Collecting cmake
        Using cached cmake-3.25.2-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (32.6 MB)
      Collecting pip
        Using cached pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
      ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 
1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9
.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.
15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.1
9.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.2
3.3, 1.23.4, 1.23.5, 1.24.0rc1, 1.24.0rc2, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

i installed torch with

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

as i found somewhere say nightly support 3.11
now i'm wondering it's torch problem or easyocr problem

if someone know what pip to run for python 3.11, if even it's supported as i can't find what version it supports

i tried different torch version, disinstalled numpy to see if

```
pip install easyocr
```

resolve it self but nothing
i also tried

```
pip install git+https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR.git
```

and

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\python\My Heroes> pip install numpy==1.21.2
```

with this output

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5
 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.
9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0, 
1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0, 1
.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.3, 1
.23.4, 1.23.5, 1.24.0rc1, 1.24.0rc2, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2
```

edit1: after someone suggested i runned by unistall my torch version first

```
pip install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

that's the pip show torch output

```
Version: 2.1.0.dev20230311+cpu
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/
Author: PyTorch Team
Author-email: packages@pytorch.org
License: BSD-3
Location: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: filelock, jinja2, networkx, sympy, typing-extensions
Required-by: torchaudio, torchvision
```

unfortunatly after running pip install easyocr the same error still reproduce, so it let me think it may be a easyOCR 3.11 support problem?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am also facing the same error and I think its because of numpy version mismatch, but that version of numpy does not seem to exist, and hence cannot be installed and the easyocr install cannot be resolved i guess

Comment: no i dind't find a solution i just changed library to tesseract

Answer (score 1):

**Updated March 2023:** If you install wrong version of OpenCV, it will give you lots of errors and it's very hard to fix.

**Solution**

```
conda create -n timm_tutorials python=3.7 (installed Python 3.7.16)
conda activate timm_tutorials
pip3 install -r requirments.txt
pip3 install matplotlib == 3.3.1
pip3 install opencv-python==4.4.0.42
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble finding a version of numpy that matches the required version `(numpy==1.21.2)`. (the error is indicating that one of the dependencies required by the EasyOCR library is the specific version of NumPy)

Try to install `numpy version 1.21.2` separately using `pip install numpy==1.21.2` and then try installing `easyocr` again using `pip install easyocr.`

Comment: give it a try and still give error

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566

PyTorch at the moment is only available as CUDA on Python 3.11 with the nightly build on Windows. It is not available as CPU that you are trying to install

Edit:
Try this to install, it may work on windows actually.

```bash
pip install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

Comment: i tried the new pip for torch and it didn't worked, i added the result in my original post

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the exact same error on a M1 Macbook Pro. I assumed at first it was the apple chip causing some issue but I don't believe that is the case now.